# How to Perform Percentage on item list Enum?

Tags: java, enums, percentage

I'm looking for some tip on how to do a percentage thing for my game I want all flowers in a range of 1-98 and white/black flowers 99-100 to make it more rarerity thanks for the help :)

```
     public enum FlowerSuit {
    WHITE_FLOWERS("white", ":white:", "470419377456414720", 1),
    YELLOW_FLOWERS("yellow", ":yellow:", "470419561267855360", 1 ),
    RED_FLOWERS("red", ":red:", "470419583250202644", 1),
    RAINBOW_FLOWERS("rainbow", ":rainbow:", "470419602841665536", 1),       
    PASTEL_FLOWERS("pastel", ":pastel:", "470419629450199040", 1),
    ORANGE_FLOWERS("orange", ":orange:", "470419647900942366", 1),
    BLUE_FLOWERS("blue", ":blue:", "470419688753594368", 1),
    BLACK_FLOWERS("black", ":black:", "470419706751352842", 1);
    private final String displayName;
    private final String emoticon;
    private int value;
    private final String id;


     FlowerSuit(String displayName, String emoticon, String id, int value ) {

        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.emoticon = emoticon;
        this.value = value;
        this.id = id;

    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public String getEmoticon() {
        return emoticon;        
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return value;
    }
```

}

Comment: You haven't explained yourself properly. Do you want to create a method that gives random flowers with black flowers being given less often?

Comment: @Richard Yes that exactley what im looking i want black and white more rare like 1 chance of 100 getting it  ,sorry my english isnot perfect

Comment: Add another parameter to the constructor of your enum called frequency or something. Make it a number between 1 and 100 where 100 is common. Create a static method that loops over the 'values' of the enum and sums the numbers. Calculate a random number between 1 and the sum. Loop over the values again.. summing till you have exceeded that number and return the matching enum. If you can't imagine what I mean I'll post an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it, but it can probably be improved, for starters by using Java 8 streams etc.

```
public enum FlowerSuit {
 WHITE_FLOWERS("white", ":white:", "470419377456414720", 1,3),
 YELLOW_FLOWERS("yellow", ":yellow:", "470419561267855360", 1,2),
 RED_FLOWERS("red", ":red:", "470419583250202644", 1,2),
 RAINBOW_FLOWERS("rainbow", ":rainbow:", "470419602841665536", 1,2),       
 PASTEL_FLOWERS("pastel", ":pastel:", "470419629450199040", 1,2),
 ORANGE_FLOWERS("orange", ":orange:", "470419647900942366", 1,2),
 BLUE_FLOWERS("blue", ":blue:", "470419688753594368", 1,2),
 BLACK_FLOWERS("black", ":black:", "470419706751352842", 1,1);
 private static Random random = new Random();
 private final String displayName;
 private final String emoticon;
 private int value;
 private final String id;
 private final int freq;

 private FlowerSuit(String displayName, String emoticon, String id, int value, int freq ) {
    this.displayName = displayName;
    this.emoticon = emoticon;
    this.value = value;        
    this.id = id;
    this.freq = freq;
}
public String getDisplayName() {return displayName;}
public String getEmoticon() {return emoticon;}
public String getId() {return id;}
public int getValue() {return value;}

/**
 * Choose a flower
 * white has a 3 in 16 (about a 5:1) chance of being picked
 * Black has a 1 in 16 chance, everything else 2/16
 * @return
 */
public static FlowerSuit pick() {
    //first sum all the chances (currently it's 16)
    int sum = 0;
    for (FlowerSuit f:FlowerSuit.values()) sum+= f.freq;
    //now choose a random number
    int r = FlowerSuit.random.nextInt(sum) + 1;
    //now find out which flower to pick
    sum = 0;
    for (FlowerSuit f:FlowerSuit.values()) {
        sum += f.freq;
        if (r<=sum) return f;           
    }
    //code will never get here
    return FlowerSuit.WHITE_FLOWERS;
}


public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Test it
    Map<FlowerSuit,Integer>count = new HashMap<FlowerSuit,Integer>();       
    for (int a=0;a<1000000;a++) {
        FlowerSuit f = FlowerSuit.pick();
        Integer i = (count.get(f)!=null)?count.get(f):new Integer(0);
        i = new Integer(i+1);
        count.put(f,i);
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<FlowerSuit,Integer>e:count.entrySet()) sum+=e.getValue();
    float f = Float.valueOf(sum);
    for (Map.Entry<FlowerSuit,Integer>e:count.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + " was chosen " + ((e.getValue() / f) * 100f) + "% of the time");
    }       
}
```

}

gives

BLUE_FLOWERS was chosen 12.4986% of the time

PASTEL_FLOWERS was chosen 12.4707% of the time

WHITE_FLOWERS was chosen 18.7365% of the time

BLACK_FLOWERS was chosen 6.2632003% of the time

ORANGE_FLOWERS was chosen 12.4986% of the time

RED_FLOWERS was chosen 12.5241995% of the time

YELLOW_FLOWERS was chosen 12.501401% of the time

RAINBOW_FLOWERS was chosen 12.5068% of the time

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `TreeMap` to map all of the integers from 0 to 99 to a particular `FlowerSuit`.  Take advantage of the `floorEntry` method to choose a `FlowerSuit` for each number.  It might look something like this.

```
public class FlowerChooser {
    private static final NavigableMap<Integer, FlowerSuit> FLOWER_SUITS;
    private static final Random RANDOMS = new Random();

    public FlowerChooser() {
        FLOWER_SUITS = new TreeMap<>();
        FLOWER_SUITS.put(0, FlowerSuit.RED_FLOWERS);
        FLOWER_SUITS.put(14, FlowerSuit.ORANGE_FLOWERS);
        FLOWER_SUITS.put(28, FlowerSuit.YELLOW_FLOWERS);
        FLOWER_SUITS.put(42, FlowerSuit.GREEN_FLOWERS);
        FLOWER_SUITS.put(56, FlowerSuit.BLUE_FLOWERS);
        FLOWER_SUITS.put(70, FlowerSuit.INDIGO_FLOWERS);
        FLOWER_SUITS.put(84, FlowerSuit.VIOLET_FLOWERS);
        FLOWER_SUITS.put(98, FlowerSuit.WHITE_FLOWERS);
        FLOWER_SUITS.put(99, FlowerSuit.BLACK_FLOWERS);
    }

    public FlowerSuit randomFlowerSuit() {
        int index = RANDOMS.nextInt(100);
        return FLOWER_SUITS.floorEntry(index).getValue();
    }
}
```

Create just one object of this class, then whenever you want a `FlowerSuit`, call the `randomFlowerSuit` method.

The `randomFlowerSuit` method picks a random number from 0 to 99, then finds an appropriate entry in the map.  The `floorEntry` method chooses an entry whose key is less than or equal to the chosen number.  This means that numbers from 0 to 13 get mapped to red, 14 to 27 get mapped to orange, and so on.  The only number that gets mapped to white is 98, and the only number that gets mapped to black is 99.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what solution you implement, you want to include a frequency measure in your enum.  As an example, you can do something like this:

```
public enum FlowerSuit {
    WHITE_FLOWERS("white", ":white:", "470419377456414720", 1, 1),
    YELLOW_FLOWERS("yellow", ":yellow:", "470419561267855360", 1, 20),
    // More declarations here

    // Add this variable
    private final int frequency;

    // Do just as you did before in the constructor, but with the frequency
    FlowerSuit(String displayName, String emoticon, String id, int value, int frequency){
        this.frequency = frequency;
        // More assignments here
    } 

    public int getFrequency(){
        return frequency;
    }

    // More getters here
}
```

This addition is critical, and no matter what method you use to weight flower selection, you will want this addition to your FlowerSuit enum.

Now, we can explore a few different ways to perform this selection.

*Note 1: I use `ThreadLocalRandom` for random numbers in a range, which is from `java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom`.*

*Note 2: For each of these, make a single instance of `FlowerPicker`, and use the `pickFlower()` method to pick the next flower.  This avoid running costly setup code over and over.*

**Method 1: Bag of Flowers**

This method is probably the easiest to implement.  It entails creating a list of enums where each is represented `frequency` times, and then selecting a random entry from this list.  It is similar to throwing a bunch of flowers in a bag, shaking it, and then reaching your hand in and grabbing the first flower you touch.  Here's the implementation:

```
public class FlowerPicker(){
    private ArrayList<FlowerSuit> bag;

    public FlowerPicker(){
        // Get all possible FlowerSuits
        FlowerSuit[] options = FlowerSuit.values();

        // You can use an array here or an array list with a defined length if you know the total of the frequencies
        bag = new ArrayList<FlowerSuit>();

        // Add each flower from options frequency times
        for (FlowerSuit flower : options)
            for (int i=0; i<flower.getFrequency(); i++)
                 bag.add(flower);
    }

    public FlowerBag pickFlower(){
        // Now, select a random flower from this list
        int randomIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, bag.size());
        return bag.get(randomIndex);
    }
}
```

This method has the advantage of being simple enough to understand very easily.  However, it can be inefficient if your frequencies are extremely specific (like if you want a rainbow flower to be returned 499,999,999 times out of 1,000,000,000).  Let's move on to the next method.

*Note 1: You could make this better by reducing the fractions representing the frequency of being chosen, but I'll leave this to you.*

*Note 2: You could also make this slightly better by storing identification numbers, not FlowerSuit objects in the `bag` list.*

**Method 2: Navigable Map**

This method is a little bit more difficult.  It uses a `[NavigableMap][1]`, which is an implementation of `[TreeMap][2]`.  This method is fairly similar to the Bag of Flowers method, but it is a little bit more efficient.  Put simply, it uses the `TreeMap` to give each `FlowerSuit` a range of numbers that can be selected to return that `FlowerSuit`.  Here's a full example:

```
public class FlowerPicker(){
    private NavigableMap<Double, FlowerSuit> map;

    public FlowerPicker(){
        // Get all possible FlowerSuits
        FlowerSuit[] options = FlowerSuit.values();

        map = new TreeMap<Double, FlowerSuit>();

        int runningTotal = 0;
        // Add each flower with the proper range
        for (FlowerSuit flower : options){
            runningTotal += flower.getFrequency();
            map.put(runningTotal, flower);
        }
    }

    public FlowerBag pickFlower(){
        // Now, select a random number and get the flower with this number in its range
        int randomRange = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, bag.size());
        return map.higherEntry(randomRange).getValue();
    }
}
```

This is a solid method, and it scales well for very specific frequencies.  If you have a bunch of different types of flowers, it will be slightly worse, but this method is still a good option at large scales. There's one more option though.

**Method 3: Enumerated Distribution**
This method is really nice because you barely have to do anything.  However, it uses `[EnumeratedDistribution][3]` from Apache Commons.  Enumerated Distribution requires a list of pairs of objects and weights.  Anyway, lets jump into it:

```
public class FlowerPicker(){
    private EnumeratedDistribution distribution;

    public FlowerPicker(){
        // Get all possible FlowerSuits
        FlowerSuit[] options = FlowerSuit.values();

        List<Pair<FlowerSuit, Double>> weights = new List<Pair<FlowerSuit, Double>>();

        // Add each flower and weight to the list
        for (FlowerSuit flower : options){
            weights.add(new Pair(flower, flower.getFrequency()));

        // Construct the actual distribution
        distribution = new EnumeratedDistribution(weights);
    }

    public FlowerBag pickFlower(){
        // Now, sample the distribution
        return distribution.sample();
    }
}
```

This is my favorite method, simply because so much of it is done for you.  Many problems like this have been solved, so why not use solutions that always exist?  However, there is some value to writing the solution yourself.

In conclusion, each of these methods are perfectly fine to use at your scale, but I would recommend the second or third method.